# This is the code for the queuing implementation. I don't know why there is a problem with the output

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, queue, output

The purpose of this code is to implement the queue, input I is to store a value, G is to retrieve a value, and E is to end the storage and retrieval work.
My problem is that I don't know why the output "[I]存入數值[G]取出數值[E]結束:" will output more than one after the first time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 20

int main()
{
    int rear = -1;
    int front = -1;
    int queue[MAX] = {0};
    char ch;
    int val;
    while (rear < MAX - 1 && ch != 'E')
    {
        printf("[I]存入數值[G]取出數值[E]結束:");
        scanf("%c", &ch);
        switch (ch)
        {
        case 'I':
            printf("請輸入數值:");
            scanf("%d", &val);
            rear++;
            queue[rear] = val;
            break;
        case 'G':
            if (rear > front)
            {
                front++;
                printf("取出的值:%d\n", queue[front]);
                queue[front] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("佇列已空!\n");
                exit(0);
            }
            break;
        default:
            printf("\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    if (rear == MAX - 1)
        printf("佇列已滿!\n");
    printf("目前佇列中的資料:");
    if (front >= rear)
    {
        printf("沒有\n");
        printf("佇列已空!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while (rear > front)
        {
            front++;
            printf("%d ", queue[front]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%c",&ch)` -> `scanf(" %c",&ch)`. Add a leading space in your format string when reading characters.

Comment: Also, when you first enter the loop, the value of `ch` will be *indeterminate* (see it like garbage). Uninitialized local variables really are uninitialized.

Comment: Thanks for your help!